# SQL Server 2012 Management Studio : Export to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, export-to-excel

I am writing a basic SQL query in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio and I have listed a result.

After I am trying to export to Excel with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+C</kbd> (Copy with headers) and I have pasted to Excel table but some rows came 2 or a lot rows.

Every rows, view just one row each other but it is viewing a lot of row.

It is look like this

```
xID           xName        xSurname       xOther
-------------------------------------------------
1             A            A              A 
2             B            B              B
3             C            C              C
4             D            D              D
```

Comment: Basically he means once he copies records from sql server query result view and pastes into an excel file, some sql records overflow and turns to 2 or more rows in excel file.
His answer saved my time. Thanks @Erkan Örmeci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found, how i can solve it.

You can solve this problem with this code :

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col, CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(9), ' ') AS Col 
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 3):

For better results query directly from Excel.Data -Get External Data - From Other sources - From Microsoft Query.

Results will returned with headers.You will be required to establish connection between Excel and your SQL Server instance.This should rid of any formatting headaches.

Comment: I agree in general, but why MS Query and not "From SQL Server"?

Comment: From sql server and i tried to in sql server with "Save Result As"   but it seems like same.

Comment: @ErkanÖrmeci, just to be clear, I was agreeing with this answer, but thinking that clicking Data>Get External Data>From Other Sources>From SQL Server might be better. The general idea is this will be easier than trying to export from SQL Server as you are doing.

Comment: I think i can't tell you actually what i want. I want to export just result datas from sql query. Actually i can did it but i am opening excel file and it has wrong rows. Every data must have a just a row but some datas have a lot of rows